# Using delegates in class methods

Tags: d

I found something in the DMD behavior that I don't understand.

My code looks like this:

```
class C1 {
    private static fun(alias f)() {
        ;
    }
    public static void run() {
        auto f = delegate bool(int x) {return true;} ;
        fun!(f)();
        return;
    }
}
```

And compiler writes an error:

```
Error: template instance fun!(f) cannot use local 'f' as parameter to non-global template fun(alias f)()
```

So I have to create a delegate field in class to make it global:

```
class C1 {
    private static fun(alias f)() {
        ;
    }
    private static bool delegate(int) f;
    public static void run() {
        f = delegate bool(int x) {return true;} ;
        fun!(f)();
        return;
    }
}
```

This code is compiled without errors. But I don't understand, why can't we declare the delegate inside of the method?

Comment: What's your goal? I think there may be better ways of doing it.  Basically 'f' is a mutable, local pointer to a delegate (and the delegate itself has a context pointer), so you can't pass it as a template param -- those must be known at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: This issue is not as simple as I originally thought. Here's what I think is really going on. As pointed out by another commenter, I was forgetting that alias template parameters allow any kind of symbol to be passed in, even local variables. In a case like this, with a function template, the instantiated template needs a pointer to its context (the body of `run`) so it can access those local variables (like the delegate `f`) passed in as alias params. However, `fun` is already a static member of a class, which means it already has a context pointer (the static class context). Now, it is a known limitation of the D compiler that it cannot handle delegates needing two or more context pointers. (That's why it says 'non-global' in the error message -- global function templates work since they don't have a context.)

The second example works because `f` is no longer a local variable; it is a static member. The fact that it is initialized in the scope of `run` doesn't change that.

See the following issues:

- http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3051
- http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3052
- http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=5710

Hopefully someone with more inside knowledge of the compiler can confirm this diagnosis.

**Original answer**

(My original answer explained this error by saying that the template param needed to be immutable and known at compile time as well as not being a delegate (plain function instead). This was only half-right ... alias params don't need to have values known at compile time. However, the part about it needing to be a regular function and not a delegate was correct.)

These workarounds from my original answer still apply:

Declaring `f` in one of these ways will ensure it can be passed as a template param:

```
// Not a delegate, not a local variable anymore (enum)
enum f = function bool(int x) {return true;};

// "static" == not delegate
static bool f(int x) { return true; }
fun!(f)();

// Or pass it as a literal (inferred to be non-delegate)
fun!((int x) => true);
```

Regular methods can be passed as template params:

```
class C2 {
    private static fun(alias f)() {
        assert(f(1) == true);
    }
    private static bool g(int) { 
        return true; 
    }
    public static void run() {
        fun!(g)();
    }
}
```

Or pass it as a regular param, not a template param:

```
class C1 {
    private static fun(bool delegate(int) f) {
        assert(f(1) == true);
    }
    public static void run() {
        auto f = delegate bool(int x) { return true; };
        fun(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Answering to your question about the goal: I had a basic private method to get the array of structures. And I wanted to have a group of public methods, based on private method, but filtering the array in some way. Then I got the idea to make the filter-function the member of private method. Then I tried to make this filter function dependent on incoming values of public methods. This seemed to me a good idea.

Comment: Yes! It should be passed like a regular parameter. That's an answer I searched.

Comment: I changed my opinion on what's really going on with this error. See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer, but here are some thoughts which don't fit well in a comment.

> Error: template instance fun!(f) cannot use **local 'f'** as parameter
>   to **non-global template** fun(alias f)()

You'll notice that there are actually two ways to resolve this problem. Either turn 'f' into a non-local variable, as you did. Or make the template global.

This suggests that there is some difficulty in instantiating a local template to a local variable. I'm guessing this means it is a technical/implementation challenge rather than a practical restriction (i.e. don't do it because...).

Update: What J. Miller isn't realizing is that an alias parameter binds to a symbol not to a value. In your case the symbol f is known at compile time and thus this code does work:

```
class C1 {
    public static void run() {
        auto f = delegate bool(int x) {return true;} ;
        fun!(f)();
        return;
    }
}

private void fun(alias f)() {
    import std.stdio;
    writeln(f(3));
}

void main () {
    new C1;
    C1.run();
}
```

Comment: You are right about alias template params. This is not as simple as I thought at first. I will update my answer... Thanks.